# image viewer website

Tags: java, jsf, image, dojo, seam

i asked to make a website to view images and manage it's actions like max, min, autofit,..... 
(some thing like picasa but as a web application )
what is the suitable tool for that. JSF, JBoos Seam, dojo, digit ?
and if any reference to enhance my skills on that branch will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Web Toolkit : http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/ is suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Seam/ richfaces project example:

http://livedemo.exadel.com/photoalbum/index.seam